# Air Play-ing music from a sleeping iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipod, music, airplay

A couple days ago, I was experimenting with Air Play. What I'd like to do is play music behind a party, driven from my iPhone in my pocket. I sleep my phone while iPod is playing music all the time, it keeps going just great, but this time it would die after a few minutes of sleeping. I believe what's happening is it's losing WiFi and killing the Air Play connection.

Any solutions for playing an evening's worth of music through Air Play from my pocket, without pulling the phone out and restarting it every few minutes?

EDIT: I should have mentioned, this phone is not jailbroken and I'd prefer not to jailbreak it. I'm a developer and my phone is one of my testing devices. I need to be able to test it in the conditions most users will be in.

Comment: Have you tried not locking your phone, and simply allowing it to time out to the lock screen?  There is some sort of difference between you giving the command to lock the screen, and it doing it itself.  Give it a go, set a timeout value in settings, and leave it to shut the screen by itself, and see if it maintains a connection/continues to play.

Comment: @stuffe I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can avoid bumping the sleep/wake button, you should have hours of playing time using AirPlay. Once the screen is dimmed due to a time-out, you can press sleep/wake to show the current track, just avoid pressing it to force an immediate sleep/screen dim. Let the timer do the work to ensure music playback.

I have Auto-Lock set at 5 minutes (with no passcode lock) and often set down my iPhone on the counter or place it in my pocket while I walk around the house, playing music until a low battery warning pauses playback. If you have to, shorten this setting during the party to avoid uncomfortable musical silences.

Answer (score -2):

There is an app in Cydia called Insomnia which keeps the wifi alive even when the iDevice is locked. Try jailbreaking - if you haven't already - and install it. Works great!